# Suppressing stack trace when catching exception

Tags: exception, spring-batch

I have a short 2 step Spring Batch job that reads from an xml rest service call using StaxEventItemReader in Strict mode. I want it in strict mode because without the ability to connect to the rest service, there is no reason to continue. I want to catch the exception and exit gracefully with a custom message, not with a stack trace.

I'm able to catch the exception using a StepExecutionListener with afterStep() method checking the failures (stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()), but the stack trace is still being output. I'm getting my custom message (13:05:32,981 in the STS Output below) plus the stack trace. When I used the ItemReaderListener with onError method the onError method is not called, I'm guessing because it is an initialization exception not a read error.

What is the best method for capturing the **failed to initialize reader** exception and suppress the stack trace from the output?

SpringBatch Job:

```html
 <batch:job id="randomSends2NG">
  <batch:step id="getStations" next="generateAndSend">
   <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk reader="getStationsFromNG_RestXML" 
        processor="idExtractor"
        writer="stationsWriter"
        commit-interval="1">
    </batch:chunk> 
    <batch:listeners>
     <batch:listener ref="noStationsStopListener" />
    </batch:listeners>  
    
   </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="generateAndSend">
   <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk reader="readStationIdsList" 
        processor="createRandomRequests"
        writer="ngBroadcasterService"
        commit-interval="400">
    </batch:chunk>   
   </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
 </batch:job>
```

STS output with stack trace:

```html
13:05:30,479 [main] INFO  SimpleJobLauncher  - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
13:05:30,776 [main] INFO  DepartmentSendCountsNoOpReader  - constructing stationSendCountsReader
LightYellow color:43
13:05:31,368 [main] INFO  ProcessStatisticsTasklet  - constructor...
13:05:31,525 [main] INFO  RequestsListReader  - constructing requestsListReader
13:05:31,588 [main] INFO  Jaxb2Marshaller  - Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class com.pevco.pevcotubesystem.StationConfig]
13:05:31,886 [main] INFO  SimpleJobLauncher  - Job: [FlowJob: [name=randomSends2NG]] launched with the following parameters: [{hostNameOrIP=192.168.100.10:8383}]
13:05:31,902 [main] INFO  SimpleStepHandler  - Executing step: [getStations]
13:05:32,981 [main] ERROR AbstractStep  - Encountered an error executing step getStations in job randomSends2NG
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.open(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
 at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:362)
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:590)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doOpen(StaxEventItemReader.java:195)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
 ... 27 more
13:05:32,981 [main] ERROR NoStationsStopListener  - Not able to get stations list from NG. Check that NG is running
13:05:32,998 [main] INFO  SimpleJobLauncher  - Job: [FlowJob: [name=randomSends2NG]] completed with the following parameters: [{hostNameOrIP=192.168.100.10:8383}] and the following status: [FAILED]
13:05:32,998 [main] INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4f4a7090: startup date [Wed Jul 01 13:05:29 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing this problem probably the best solution is to check for REST service as soon as possible because *"without the ability to connect to the rest service, there is no reason to continue [...] and exit gracefully with a custom message"*.
Before first step use a [JobExecutionDecider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html) where you check for REST availability and continue or end your job according to service presence/absence.